# Unable to generate a PDF using XeLatex after fresh Windows Installation

Tags: xetex

Everything was working fine a week ago and I was getting the PDF of my MCQs compiled in XeLatex using following MWE. After installing a fresh copy of Windows, I am unable to generate PDF. The necessary file to be loaded with this MWE is given below named [mcq](https://www.dlfer.xyz/var/_downloads/a7a670f40b50b15891accdb8ccfb2d2a/mcq.sty).

```
%===================================================================
\documentclass[onesided,a4paper,leqno]{article}
%===================================================================
\usepackage{mathpazo} % I like it.
\usepackage[bubblesheet]{mcq}
\englishinfo %% this if you want English sentences.
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} %% it needs to be *after* mcq.

%===================================================================
\headline{\textbf{\large MCQs HYPOTHESIS TESTING}}
%% this is the "name" of the exam
%  http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/java/MultipleChoice/logic.txt
%  http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/java/MultipleChoice/MultipleChoice.html

\puntigiusta{6} % points for a correct answer
\puntisbagliata{-1} % points for a wrong answer (when not explicitely stated)
\puntiempty{0} % points for non-response.


%===================================================================
% The following is necessary only if bubblesheet...
% \UIDdigits{5}
% change it if the default value (6) does not fit.


%===================================================================
% This is the text appearing on the right of the UID matrix.
% It is safe to change it (but it should be not too long...)
%\renewcommand{\geninfo}{%
%Instructions: fill \textbf{completely} the bubbles
%with the digits of the SID (one for each column);
%in the lower part of the sheet, fill \textbf{completely}
%the bubble with the correct answers to the corresponding question.
%Use a black or dark blue pen or pencil,
%trying to fill completely the inside of the bubble.
%Write only in the designated areas.
%}
%\renewcommand{\ansinfo}{\textbf{Mark the answers of the multiple-choice questions}}
%\renewcommand{\uidname}{Student ID}
%\renewcommand{\Cognomename}{Last Name}
%\renewcommand{\Nomename}{First name}
%\renewcommand{\Firmaname}{Signature}

% the previous commands are equivalent to the command
% \englishinfo


% It is safe to renew \squarebox: empty for no-squarebox,
% or whatever Unicode character or symbol. It is the symbol appearing
% on the left of each possible item-answer. Check that the characters
% is included in the font...
% \renewcommand{\squarebox}{--}

% If changing the font, make sure that it's not too ugly.
% \setmainfont[mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
%===================================================================
% just some newcommands
%===================================================================
\begin{document}
\bubblesheet[2]{20}{5}
% [number of columns] {number of questions} {number of answers}

\begin{esercizi*}{}
% enviroment including the questions.
% The second argument is the tile of the exercises section.

\begin{exerm}%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MCQ#001  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The idea of testing of hypothesis was first set forth by
\begin{rispm}[4] % the optional parameters is the number of columns
\risp R. A. Fisher
\risp[=] J. Neyman
\risp E. L. Lehman
\risp A. Wald
\end{rispm}
\end{exerm}

\begin{exerm}%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MCQ#002  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    In 1933, the theory of testing of hypotheses was propounded by
\begin{rispm}[2] % the optional parameters is the number of columns
\risp R. A. Fisher
\risp J. Neyman
\risp E. L. Lehman
\risp[=] Karl Pearson
\end{rispm}
\end{exerm}

\end{esercizi*}
\end{document}
```

A solution is required for this issue.

I am using Winedt with newer version of Miktex.

Comment: No errors when compiling with TeX Live 2020 (Overleaf). The problem seem not to stem from your code.

Comment: check for updates, there was a bug last week which prevented the creation of the xelatex format. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/753

Comment: What is the solution than, if i am using miktex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, what is the solution?

Comment: As I wrote: Go to the miktex console (admin mode) and update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, "There are currently no updates." I have updated all the packages and installed all the updates. But still I am unable to process my code.

Comment: which error do you get? what does the log-file say?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, following are the last lines of the log

Comment: [2] (AGG Hypothesis Testing.aux)
dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (2)

No output PDF file written.
 )
Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;
file AGG Hypothesis Testing.pdf may not be valid.
SyncTeX written on AGG Hypothesis Testing.synctex.
Transcript written on "AGG Hypothesis Testing.log".

Comment: looks like a problem with a font, try to remove mathpazo.

Comment: After removing the \usepackage{mathpazo} command, problem is still the same.

Comment: No solution yet for this issue? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: it works fine for me on windows + miktex. Run xelatex on a command line with the option `--output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv"` , perhaps you can then see which font is the problem.